# Hot Chocolate GraphQL - MaxExecutionDepth not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

How do I get `MaxExecutionDepth` to work in Hot Chocolate GraphQL? Here is my code:

```
    // Add GraphQL Services
    services.AddGraphQL(
        SchemaBuilder.New()
            // enable for authorization support
            .AddAuthorizeDirectiveType()
            .ModifyOptions(o => o.RemoveUnreachableTypes = true)
            .Create()
            .MakeExecutable(
                builder =>
                    builder
                        .UseDefaultPipeline()
                        .AddErrorFilter<UseExceptionMessageErrorFilter>()
                        .AddOptions(
                            new QueryExecutionOptions()
                            {
                                MaxExecutionDepth = 15
                            }))
            .Schema);
```

I've tested with this, even changing `MaxExecutionDepth` to 1, but I can still execute 20+ deep queries.

Comment: Have you tried to move use setting in the [`Create` call](https://hotchocolate.io/docs/general-schema-options#__docusaurus)

Comment: @GuruStron not sure what you mean; `Create()` takes no params.

Comment: Oh, i misread API, sorry.

Comment: Added a answer, please try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the developer in the [GitHub issue I created](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/1881), was able to get it working like this:

```
            services.AddGraphQL(
                SchemaBuilder.New()
                    // enable for authorization support
                    .AddAuthorizeDirectiveType()
                    .ModifyOptions(o => o.RemoveUnreachableTypes = true)
                    .Create(),
                new QueryExecutionOptions()
                {
                    MaxExecutionDepth = ApiConfigurationConstants.MaxExecutionDepth
                });
            services.AddErrorFilter<UseExceptionMessageErrorFilter>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question and answer are more than 3 years old, so for anyone else like myself who ran into this issue now, this is another option (V13 of HotChocolate):

In your `Program.cs` modify the GraphQl server section like this and add `AddMaxExecutionDepthRule`:

```
builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<GraphQlQuery>()
    .AddProjections()
    .AddFiltering()
    .AddSorting()
    .AddMaxExecutionDepthRule(5);
```

Here 5 (or any other number) is the depth that you want.

Reference: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/security#execution-depth